# Promises in a While Loop where condition of while is based on result of the promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I need to do an indeterminate loop where the condition of the loop will be based on the response from a promise within the loop that gets some data from a database. The loop should be done from within a promise that then returns the total list of records pulled from the database. This is somewhat simplified from the real world example, but have tried to provide some basic code to demonstrate what I want essentially to do.

The call to getLinkedEntities passes in an entity and based on a linked entity id begins the loop where linked entities are returned and then returned from the original promise.

The problem I have is that because of the asynchronous nature of promises the moment getElement is called within the while loop it never resolves because the function continues and gets stuck in continuous loop.

Hopefully this code describes well enough what I am trying to do, i.e. end up with an array of linked entities, but how can it be done in a synchronous way that allows all promises to return?

```
   function getLinkedEntities(startEntity) { 
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            var linkedEntities = [];
            var entityId = startEntity.id;
            var someOtherId = startEntity.linkedentityid;

            var stopLoop = false;

            do {

                getElement(someOtherId).then(function (entity) {
                    linkedEntities.push(entity)
                    entityId = entity.id;
                    someOtherId = entity.linkedentityid;
                    stopLoop = entity.linkedentityid === null ? 1 : 0;
                });

            }
            while (!stopLoop);

            resolve(linkedEntities);

        });
    }

    function getElement(id) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            // go to database and get an entity
            resolve(entity);
        });
    }

    getLinkedEntities(someEntity).then(function (response) {
        // do somethign with linkedEntities
    });
```

Comment: what you want to use is perhaps setInterval or setTimeout instead of while loop. In case of setInterval, dont forget to clean-up.

Comment: Is that not a problem when the interval will need to allow for database call that could take indeterminate length?

Comment: setInterval will trigger the  method every X milliseconds. It can run forever as long as page is loaded afaik. That is why you have to clean it once it should resolve. setTimeout will trigger only once after X milliseconds. If condition is not fulfilled, you can set another timeout in handler.

Comment: This can be done by calling the function from within itself.  But if you can use `async/await` it is much easier, and you can keep your while logic.

Comment: Use either `async`/`await` or a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `async / await`, what you can do is create an inner function, that calls itself.

eg.

```
  ...
  function getNext() {
     return getElement(someOtherId).then(function (entity) {
       linkedEntities.push(entity)
       entityId = entity.id;
       someOtherId = entity.linkedentityid;
       stopLoop = entity.linkedentityid === null ? 1 : 0;
       if (stopLoop) return resolve(linkedEntities);
       else return getNext();
     });
  }
  //boot strap the loop
  return getNext();
}
```

Basically this just keeps calling `getNext` until `stopLoop` is set, and then resolves `linkedEntities`, if not it calls `getNext` again.  IOW: exactly what your while loop is doing.

Below is a working snippet that uses this idea, instead of `getElement`, I've replaced with a sleep promise.  Basically fill's an array waiting 500ms between each array push.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

function test() {
  var ret = [];
  function getNext() {
    return sleep(500).then(function () {
      if (ret.length >= 10) {
        return ret;
      } else {
        console.log('tick: ' + ret.length);
        ret.push(ret.length + 1);
        return getNext();
      }
    });
  }
  return getNext();
}

test().then(function (r) {
  console.log('Resolved with ->');
  console.log(r.join(','));
});
```

Comment: Maybe im misunderstanding how Promises work, but when I try this the moment the first call to getElement resolves, the callback to that in getNext, being asynchronous, never fires and getNext immediately returns

Comment: @StewartAlan  `getNext` will always return immediately.  But it returns a Promise, from this promise you have the `then`able, callback.  Basically what we are doing is promise chaining.   A little note: make sure you `return`, otherwise promise chaining will fail.

Comment: Im still confused. I have an outer promise that needs to resolve the final value of linkedEntities array. Can you provide a code example where that promise executes getNext and doesnt resolve until stopLoop is true. Im admittedly new to promises and finding this a little tough to wrap my head around

Comment: @StewartAlan  I've created a working snippet for you to have a look at, it's basically working in the same way your after.

Comment: Can confirm that code works as expected, but its only working because of the forced timeout in the sleep promise, so Im still unsure how that helps me. In my case, where you are calling sleep I need to call an existing Promise that queries the database and resolves the result. I still cant see how I can achieve that using your code in synchronous manner.